# npm install in Yeoman-Grunt build

Tags: node.js, angularjs, yeoman

I am building an angular application with yeoman.

I had set the proxy and registry

I did the following steps.

1.npm install -g yo grunt-cli bower

2.npm install -g generator-angular

3.mkdir yeoman-contacts && cd yeoman-contacts

4.yo angular:app yeomanContactsApp

After this,I got following error

```
npm ERR! EEXIST, mkdir 'C:\Users\Documents\nodejs\yeoman-contacts\node_modules\grunt-contrib-imagemin\node_modules\pngquant-bin\node_modules\bin-wrapper\node_modul
g'
File exists: C:\Users\Documents\nodejs\yeoman-contacts\node_modules\grunt-contrib-imagemin\node_modules\pngquant-bin\node_modules\bin-wrapper\node_modules\mout\str
Move it away, and try again.

npm ERR! System Windows_NT 6.1.7601
npm ERR! command "C:\\Users\\\Documents\\tools\\nodejs\\nodejs\\\\node.exe" "C:\\Users\\\Documents\\tools\\nodejs\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.j
npm ERR! cwd C:\Users\Documents\nodejs\yeoman-contacts
npm ERR! node -v v0.10.7
npm ERR! npm -v 1.2.14
npm ERR! path C:\Users\Documents\nodejs\yeoman-contacts\node_modules\grunt-contrib-imagemin\node_modules\pngquant-bin\node_modules\bin-wrapper\node_modules\mout\st
npm ERR! fstream_path C:\Users\Documents\nodejs\yeoman-contacts\node_modules\grunt-contrib-imagemin\node_modules\pngquant-bin\node_modules\bin-wrapper\node_modules
pascalCase.js
npm ERR! fstream_type File
npm ERR! fstream_class FileWriter
npm ERR! code EEXIST
npm ERR! errno 47
npm ERR! fstream_stack C:\Users\Documents\tools\nodejs\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\fstream\lib\writer.js:171:23
npm ERR! fstream_stack C:\Users\Documents\tools\nodejs\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\mkdirp\index.js:37:53
npm ERR! fstream_stack Object.oncomplete (fs.js:107:15)
npm ERR! error rolling back Error: ENOTEMPTY, rmdir 'C:\Users\Documents\nodejs\yeoman-contacts\node_modules\grunt-contrib-imagemin\node_modules\optipng-bin\node_mo
pper\node_modules\mout\src\string'
npm ERR! error rolling back  grunt-contrib-imagemin@0.3.0 { [Error: ENOTEMPTY, rmdir 'C:\Users\Documents\nodejs\yeoman-contacts\node_modules\grunt-contrib-imagemin
\optipng-bin\node_modules\bin-wrapper\node_modules\mout\src\string']
npm ERR! error rolling back   errno: 53,
npm ERR! error rolling back   code: 'ENOTEMPTY',
npm ERR! error rolling back   path: 'C:\\Users\\\Documents\\nodejs\\yeoman-contacts\\node_modules\\grunt-contrib-imagemin\\node_modules\\optipng-bin\\node_modules\
\node_modules\\mout\\src\\string' }
npm ERR! jpegtran-bin@0.2.3 postinstall: `node lib/check.js`
npm ERR! `cmd "/c" "node lib/check.js"` failed with 8
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the jpegtran-bin@0.2.3 postinstall script.
npm ERR! This is most likely a problem with the jpegtran-bin package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     node lib/check.js
npm ERR! You can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls jpegtran-bin
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! System Windows_NT 6.1.7601
npm ERR! command "C:\\Users\\\Documents\\tools\\nodejs\\nodejs\\\\node.exe" "C:\\Users\\\Documents\\tools\\nodejs\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.j
npm ERR! cwd C:\Users\Documents\nodejs\yeoman-contacts
npm ERR! node -v v0.10.7
npm ERR! npm -v 1.2.14
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! error rolling back Error: ENOTEMPTY, rmdir 'C:\Users\Documents\nodejs\yeoman-contacts\node_modules\grunt-contrib-imagemin\node_modules\gifsicle\node_modul
r\node_modules\download\node_modules\decompress\node_modules\tar\node_modules\block-stream'
npm ERR! error rolling back  gifsicle@0.1.4 { [Error: ENOTEMPTY, rmdir 'C:\Users\Documents\nodejs\yeoman-contacts\node_modules\grunt-contrib-imagemin\node_modules\
_modules\bin-wrapper\node_modules\download\node_modules\decompress\node_modules\tar\node_modules\block-stream']
npm ERR! error rolling back   errno: 53,
npm ERR! error rolling back   code: 'ENOTEMPTY',
npm ERR! error rolling back   path: 'C:\\Users\\\Documents\\nodejs\\yeoman-contacts\\node_modules\\grunt-contrib-imagemin\\node_modules\\gifsicle\\node_modules\\bi
de_modules\\download\\node_modules\\decompress\\node_modules\\tar\\node_modules\\block-stream' }
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Additional logging details can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Documents\nodejs\yeoman-contacts\npm-debug.log
npm ERR! not ok code 0
npm http GET http://registry.npmjs.org/zeparser/0.0.5
npm http 200 http://registry.npmjs.org/zeparser/0.0.5
npm http GET http://registry.npmjs.org/zeparser/-/zeparser-0.0.5.tgz
npm http 200 http://registry.npmjs.org/zeparser/-/zeparser-0.0.5.tgz
npm ERR! error rolling back Error: ENOTEMPTY, rmdir 'C:\Users\Documents\nodejs\yeoman-contacts\node_modules\karma\node_modules\socket.io\node_modules\socket.io-cli
les\ws'
npm ERR! error rolling back  socket.io-client@0.9.16 { [Error: ENOTEMPTY, rmdir 'C:\Users\Documents\nodejs\yeoman-contacts\node_modules\karma\node_modules\socket.i
s\socket.io-client\node_modules\ws']
npm ERR! error rolling back   errno: 53,
npm ERR! error rolling back   code: 'ENOTEMPTY',
npm ERR! error rolling back   path: 'C:\\Users\\\Documents\\nodejs\\yeoman-contacts\\node_modules\\karma\\node_modules\\socket.io\\node_modules\\socket.io-client\\
\ws' }
npm ERR! Error: ENOENT, lstat 'C:\Users\Documents\nodejs\yeoman-contacts\node_modules\karma\node_modules\socket.io\node_modules\socket.io-client\node_modules\ws\li
js'
npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this log at:
npm ERR!     <http://github.com/isaacs/npm/issues>
npm ERR! or email it to:
npm ERR!     <npm-@googlegroups.com>

npm ERR! System Windows_NT 6.1.7601
npm ERR! command "C:\\Users\\\Documents\\tools\\nodejs\\nodejs\\\\node.exe" "C:\\Users\\\Documents\\tools\\nodejs\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.j
"grunt-karma" "karma-ng-html2js-preprocessor" "karma-ng-scenario" "--save-dev"
npm ERR! cwd C:\Users\Documents\nodejs\yeoman-contacts
npm ERR! node -v v0.10.7
npm ERR! npm -v 1.2.14
npm ERR! path C:\Users\Documents\nodejs\yeoman-contacts\node_modules\karma\node_modules\socket.io\node_modules\socket.io-client\node_modules\ws\lib\Validation.js
npm ERR! fstream_path C:\Users\Documents\nodejs\yeoman-contacts\node_modules\karma\node_modules\socket.io\node_modules\socket.io-client\node_modules\ws\lib\Validat
npm ERR! fstream_type File
npm ERR! fstream_class FileWriter
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! errno 34
npm ERR! fstream_stack C:\Users\Documents\tools\nodejs\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\fstream\lib\writer.js:284:26
npm ERR! fstream_stack Object.oncomplete (fs.js:107:15)
npm ERR! Error: ENOENT, lstat 'C:\Users\Documents\nodejs\yeoman-contacts\node_modules\karma\node_modules\socket.io\node_modules\socket.io-client\node_modules\uglif
t\compress\test\ifreturn2.js'
npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this log at:
npm ERR!     <http://github.com/isaacs/npm/issues>
npm ERR! or email it to:
npm ERR!     <npm-@googlegroups.com>

npm ERR! System Windows_NT 6.1.7601
npm ERR! command "C:\\Users\\\Documents\\tools\\nodejs\\nodejs\\\\node.exe" "C:\\Users\\\Documents\\tools\\nodejs\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.j
"grunt-karma" "karma-ng-html2js-preprocessor" "karma-ng-scenario" "--save-dev"
npm ERR! cwd C:\Users\Documents\nodejs\yeoman-contacts
npm ERR! node -v v0.10.7
npm ERR! npm -v 1.2.14
npm ERR! path C:\Users\Documents\nodejs\yeoman-contacts\node_modules\karma\node_modules\socket.io\node_modules\socket.io-client\node_modules\uglify-js\test\unit\co
freturn2.js
npm ERR! fstream_path C:\Users\Documents\nodejs\yeoman-contacts\node_modules\karma\node_modules\socket.io\node_modules\socket.io-client\node_modules\uglify-js\test
s\test\ifreturn2.js
npm ERR! fstream_type File
npm ERR! fstream_class FileWriter
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! errno 34
npm ERR! fstream_stack C:\Users\Documents\tools\nodejs\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\fstream\lib\writer.js:284:26
npm ERR! fstream_stack Object.oncomplete (fs.js:107:15)
npm ERR! Error: shasum check failed for C:\Users\AppData\Local\Temp\npm-4680\1390198195771-0.675874836044386\tmp.tgz
npm ERR! Expected: 03726561bc268f2e5444f54c665b7fd4a8c029e2
npm ERR! Actual:   3301543460c44351f1395479a95bc5a06dd1a8c4
npm ERR!     at C:\Users\Documents\tools\nodejs\nodejs\node_modules\npm\lib\utils\sha.js:29:20
npm ERR!     at ReadStream.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Documents\tools\nodejs\nodejs\node_modules\npm\lib\utils\sha.js:49:5)
npm ERR!     at ReadStream.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:117:20)
npm ERR!     at _stream_readable.js:910:16
npm ERR!     at process._tickCallback (node.js:415:13)
npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this log at:
npm ERR!     <http://github.com/isaacs/npm/issues>
npm ERR! or email it to:
npm ERR!     <npm-@googlegroups.com>

npm ERR! System Windows_NT 6.1.7601
npm ERR! command "C:\\Users\\\Documents\\tools\\nodejs\\nodejs\\\\node.exe" "C:\\Users\\\Documents\\tools\\nodejs\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.j
"grunt-karma" "karma-ng-html2js-preprocessor" "karma-ng-scenario" "--save-dev"
npm ERR! cwd C:\Users\Documents\nodejs\yeoman-contacts
npm ERR! node -v v0.10.7
npm ERR! npm -v 1.2.14
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Additional logging details can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Documents\nodejs\yeoman-contacts\npm-debug.log
npm ERR! not ok code 0
```

The folders are not getting created properly

"components" folder is missing

What may be the reason?

What should I do?

Please Advice

Answer (score 3):

We had a similar problem because the path was too deep. Windows by default can only handle so many characters in your directory name, and the whole `node_modules` directory structure can go quite deep! We moved the project directory to `c:\proj\` to prevent this on our Windows boxes. See also: http://kmile.nl/post/73956428426/npm-vagrant-and-symlinks-on-windows

Comment: We just copied the entire project root directory to a 'short' directory name. Our `npm` installs it's dependencies in `node_modules` in the project root, so we didn't have to change anything else.